# Super high resolution but tiny fonts combined with "normal" resolution screen

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, dell

I've got a dell xps13 with an amazing resolution of 3200 x 1800.

At work, I like to use a dual setup with an external 22 inch screen attached to it (this serves as primary screen). I use Kubuntu (so KDE as desktop environment).

The problem is that I change the font dpi settings (this works great, in the fonts menu under system settings) in order to get readable (versus tiny) letters on my laptop screen. When I plug in the second screen, all fonts are huge, the laptop's fonts are normal.

Is there any way to combine the two and use different dpi (or even better, automatic) dpi settings per screen?

Comment: Same here, although my problem is a bit less evident since I opted for the FullHD resolution instead of the 3200x1800. Every time I plug the external monitor I have to change the fonts DPI, logout and log back in. Same when disconnecting.

Comment: I have tinkered with xrandr from the command line (the scale setting), but it does not yield good results (one of the screens gets blurry). Also, it could be possible to set the DPI independently using some sort of magic in xorg.conf. I did not have time to try.

Comment: Yes, if I use only one monitor as primary screen (and ignore the huge letters son my display), I have to change the dpi and log back in and out. Annoying to do so each time I arrive at work or in and out of a meeting... It would be great to have this option in Kscreen.

Comment: Still waiting on this one...

Comment: Yes. Now I am on Kubuntu 16.04 with backports, that is KDE 5.6. If you go to System Settings > Display and monitor > Display configuration, there is a Scale display button that should allow you to scale the entire display. Unfortunately, it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Palantir, I just tried that, indeed, doesn't seem to work. Too bad!

Answer (score 1):

Since at least Kubuntu 16.04 this is pretty easy to solve: Go to
`System Settings -> Display`, choose your Displays one by one and click on the `Scale Display` bar at the very bottom.

You can scale your Content (including the fonts) up to 3 times the original size in that menu. Kubuntu remembers the settings per display.

Note that you might need to log out and log in again to see the changes.